# How to transfer files from external storage device to Nextcloud Snap?

Tags: server, php, snap, external-hdd, nextcloud

I recently set up the Nextcloud Snap package through an Ubuntu Server 22.04 VM, and most things are working. However, I'm having trouble migrating my data over from an external 2TB drive to the server's internal 8TB drive. I tried moving the data from the drive to `/var/snap/nextcloud/common/nextcloud/data/constancies/files` as root, but the files don't appear in the web interface, and deleting folders here also does nothing. I found a guide online that seemed like it would help with this (https://help.nextcloud.com/t/tutorial-how-to-migrate-mass-data-to-a-new-nextcloud-server/9418), but it says to run the command `sudo -u www-data php console.php files:scan --all` to force scan the filesystem. However, trying to run this just gives me this error: `sudo: php: command not found`.
I'm pretty sure this is because the guide uses the Docker installation of Nextcloud, so then, what about the Snap version?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just move files into the nextcloud dir they won't appear in the Webinterface. You'll also have to index them with the `occ files:scan` command

https://help.nextcloud.com/t/using-occ-on-snap-nextcloud-installation/107129